# What happens when revoking write_dac

Tags: windows, privileges, rights, access-rights

**The Scenario:**
If a user has write_dac right and he (user) granted some rights to other users.
After that, the administrator revoked write_dac from this user.

**The Question:**
What happens to the rights that has been granted to other users will be revoked or not?
Does it depends? On what?

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not keep track of who added which ACEs to an ACL.  Therefore, it has no way to remove the ACEs that were added by a particular user, even if it wanted to.

Comment: thank you That makes sense
By The way do you know any professional book or manual by windows that can be useful for windows security administration?